# I want to show my tab/menu bar items on the top instead of bottom using Xcode.How to do it?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode11, swift5

I want to show my tab/menu bar items on the top instead of bottom using Xcode.How to do it?
I am Using Swift5 and Xcode 11, but not able to show my tabs on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Working example :

1. Create a new file.
2. Select source cocoa touch class.
3. Designate subclass of: UITabBarController
4. Name the class "CustomTabBarController" or whatever you'd like.
5. Add the following code to the class.

   `override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
     super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
     var tabFrame:CGRect = self.tabBar.frame
     tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y
     self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
    }`

If you're using storyboard make sure to change the tab bar class to your custom class via the "Identity inspector".